# MASM Pointers implementation

Tags: pointers, assembly, masm

I am working on an MASM project and I think I have everything down / ready to go, expect I am having a pointer issue I believe and I just am not seeing it.  When I debug it, it results in a buffer overflow.

EDIT:

Some more info.  The error seems to be around the line:  I believe it has to do with one of my compare statements / values that I am passing so that its not catching on the return when b / a and then testing it a is equal to 0.

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset]
```

CODE:

```
.model flat
.686
.STACK 4096

pDepthOffset  EQU 8
nAOffset      EQU 12
nBOffset      EQU 16

.data

nTempSwap dd  ?
.code

_GCD_ASM@12  PROC  PUBLIC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ebx

    ;ndepth += 1 section.  
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + pDepthOffset]
    add     eax, 1
    mov     DWORD PTR[EBP + pDepthOffset], EAX
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nAOffset]

    ;if b < a
    cmp     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset]
    jae     returnsection

;SWAP section
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR[EBP + nAOffset]                        ; saving off A value.  
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset]                        ; saving off B value
    mov     DWORD PTR[EBP + nAOffset], eax                        ; storinng my B into A
    mov     DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset], ecx                        ; storinng my A into B


;checking if equal to 0
returnsection:
    cmp     DWORD PTR[EBP + nAOffset], 0
    jne     callingSection
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset]
    jmp     finish

callingSection:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nAOffset]
    push    eax
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset]
    sub     ecx, DWORD PTR[EBP + nAOffset]
    push    ecx
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR[EBP + pDepthOffset]
    push    edx
    call    _GCD_ASM@12

finish:
    pop     ebx
    pop     ebp
    ret     12
_GCD_ASM@12  ENDP
END
```

Comment: `add     esp, 12` <-- why do you have this after calling what appears to be a `stdcall` function?

Comment: Thanks!  Was remnant from when I had a cdecl print function in there trying to debug some previous errors; but I am still having issues.

Comment: Please provide more information. Where is the buffer overflow? (Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to catch the overflow in the act?)

Comment: The overflow is happening with line mov     eax, DWORD PTR[EBP + nBOffset], so basically right when I finish.  My first test case that its failing on is with a a 3 and a 7, which should return 1.  I feel like its not catching on one of my compares.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ret 12` to remove 12 bytes from the stack, but only adding 12 bytes to the stack if you branch to `callingSection` (immediately before the line that seems to corrupt the stack, which is partially true).

You can either remove the parameter from your `ret` instruction and instead add  `add esp, 12` following `call _GCD_ASM@12`, or you can use separate cleanup routines rather than jump to a common `finish:`

Comment: I don't think that is the error, as I had previously had the add esp, 12 in the function beforehand.  It is a standard call so it should jump into the finish: part for each call and clean up the stack.  I verified to make sure, but I do still have the error.